# Запуск консоли через Python

Tags: python, консоль

Возможно ли запустить консольную программу через python в Jupyter?
Хочу использовать mystem для обработки текста в инфинитив.
Если есть другие варианты - буду признателен.

Comment: Участники выше уже ответили. Советую прочитать [статью](https://habr.com/ru/company/wunderfund/blog/316826/), она развеет Ваши вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

Да, для этого надо поставить ! перед названием команды. Пример - `!ls`

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен по поводу Jupyter, но в Python есть библиотека [subprocess](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-subprocess.html), позволяющая выполнять консольные команды внутри своего кода и получать вывод этой команды.

Пример:

```py
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(
...     "ls non_existent_file; exit 0",
...     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
...     shell=True)
...
'ls: non_existent_file: No such file or directory\n'
```